# Upcoming Friends BirthDay List from Facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, fql.multiquery

How can I get the list of upcoming b'days of my friends with user id, name and birth day. I am using following fql query to get the friends b'day list.

```
  query = "SELECT uid, name, birthday_date FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) ORDER BY birthday_date DESC LIMIT 50 ";
```

Comment: I want the Upcoming friends B'day list from facebook.

Comment: And your FQL query is working. So what is your question ?

Comment: This fql query is working but it's return the top 50 friends birthday list in DESC order but not upcoming birthday list. I want the upcoming B'day list

Comment: Why not sort client side, or ask only for birthdays in a particular range?

Comment: What about removing the LIMIT 50 ? For the upcoming birthday, I don't think FQL is good enough to allow you that, so you'll have to do the sorting by yourself

Comment: Limiting is not major I can remove that but I need list in ordered with upcoming birth date

Comment: Like that `SELECT uid, name, birthday_date FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me()) and birthday_date >= "06/08" and birthday_date <= "06/15" ORDER BY birthday_date ASC LIMIT 500` ?

Comment: Null response     06-08 22:27:05.450: INFO/System.out(2651): Response : []

Comment: It works on my graph API explorer, can you try it there ? https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

Comment: Hey thanks a Lot Scharron its working it was null because their no friend's b'day in this range you can post this as answer i will accept that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your FQL query to :

```
SELECT uid, name, birthday_date FROM user
WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1=me())
AND birthday_date >= "06/08"
AND birthday_date <= "06/15"
ORDER BY birthday_date ASC
```

This will constraint the date to the next week, ordered by the next available birthday.

Comment: Hey Scharron their I one more problem this query sorted my result but not accurately. as I am trying with this condition birthday_date >= 01/01 and birthday_date <= 01/01 it returns with the list of birthday in January. :(

Comment: Its don't care about the date It is just checking the Month

Comment: Can you try with `birthday_date >= "01/01" and birthday_date < "01/02"` ?